# iOS - Allow my app to display information on lock screen?

Tags: ios, timer, lockscreen

Is it possible to display information on the lock screen from within my app? For instance, a countdown timer? I know Apple's built in apps, like the clock, can do this. But is it public API available?

And no, I am not talking about Push or Local Notifications. I want to display and actual countdown timer for my purposes so that users can shut the app and get an update on the timer by glancing at the lock screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible as far as I know.

One way to access the lock screen is by playing audio and displaying media artwork, so I'm wondering if you could create a playlist that changes songs very fast and the album artwork is an image of the current time.. Probably this isn't even close to what you want, but I'm afraid no public API can do what you want.

Comment: How does the iOS Alarm app display a countdown timer for snooze.? It appears that this can be done somehow.